# Making 2 threads alternate when executing different method on the same object

Tags: java, multithreading, class

I have two classes that represent a thread in java, Implementing Runnable interface, And a class named that that holds 2 integers as class variables (x and y).

I want to performs 2 simple actions, One is add x and y some random numbers, dx and dy respectively.
(Update method)

And the other action is return the difference between x and y.
(getDiff method)

The Data class:

```
public class Data{
 private int x = 0;
 private int y = 0;
 public Data (int x, int y){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 }
 public int getDiff(){
 return (Math.abs(x,-y));
 }
 public void update(int dx, int dy){
 x = x + dx;
 y = y + dy;
 }
}
```

One thread is supposed to execute update(int dx, int dy) 10 times, and the other thread is supposed to execute getDiff 10 times. They need to print the the outcome (diff , or the new values of x and y after the update) and sleep 10 ms in between

I want the thread to alternate, So here is what i did:

Thread_1 Class run method:

```
@Override
    public void run() {

        int rnd_x = 0;
        int rnd_y = 0;

        for (int i = 0 ; i<10; i++)
        {
            rnd_x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            rnd_y = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            data_obj.update(rnd_x,rnd_y);
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Randomized " + rnd_x + " For x and " + rnd_y + " For y, New x: " + data_obj.getX() + ", New y: " + data_obj.getY());


            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Thread_2 run method:

```
 @Override
    public void run() {

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Difference number " + i + " Is: " + data_obj.getDiff());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
    }
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Data data_1 = new Data(1,1);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Thread_1(data_1));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Thread_2(data_1));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
```

Update and getdiff after my changes:

```
public synchronized int getDiff() {
            if (!flag)
            {
                notify();
                flag = true;
                return (Math.abs(x - y));


            }
            else {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        return (Math.abs(x - y));
    }

    public synchronized void update(int dx, int dy) {

                if (flag)
                {
                    x = x + dx;
                    y = y + dy;
                    notify();
                    flag = false;
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
       }
```

I tried to use a flag and synchronized to make them alternate, But it doesn't work.
How can I make them alternate and why what I tried to do doesn't work?

Example of a desired output:

```
Thread 2: Difference number 0 Is: 0
Thread 1: Randomized 0 For x and 5 For y, New x: 1, New y: 6
Thread 2: Difference number 1 Is: 5
Thread 1: Randomized 0 For x and 4 For y, New x: 1, New y: 10
Thread 2: Difference number 2 Is: 9
Thread 1: Randomized 9 For x and 0 For y, New x: 10, New y: 10
Thread 2: Difference number 3 Is: 0
Thread 1: Randomized 8 For x and 1 For y, New x: 18, New y: 11
Thread 2: Difference number 4 Is: 7
Thread 1: Randomized 3 For x and 7 For y, New x: 21, New y: 18
Thread 2: Difference number 5 Is: 3
Thread 1: Randomized 7 For x and 8 For y, New x: 28, New y: 26
Thread 2: Difference number 6 Is: 2
Thread 1: Randomized 8 For x and 6 For y, New x: 36, New y: 32
Thread 2: Difference number 7 Is: 4
Thread 1: Randomized 3 For x and 5 For y, New x: 39, New y: 37
Thread 2: Difference number 8 Is: 2
Thread 1: Randomized 9 For x and 4 For y, New x: 48, New y: 41
Thread 2: Difference number 9 Is: 7
Thread 1: Randomized 2 For x and 7 For y, New x: 50, New y: 48
```

Comment: You say "it doesn't work" but don't explain what behavior you observe. All that seems wrong with your code is that after `wait` returns, you don't check `flag` again. You want more like `while (flag) wait(); notify(); flag = false; <rest of function>` and `while (!flag) wait(); notify(); flag = true; <rest of function>`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple mechanism to do what you want. Generally with threads it's a free-for-all - if the machine wants thread1 to execute for 1000 cycles before thread2 gets a look-in there's nothing you can do about it!

So if you do want them to wait for each other you'll have to explicity ask for it. There's a tool in java to do this called a [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). You basically need to do something like this:

```java
        //2 because we have 2 threads in this example
        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2); 
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Thread_1(data_1, barrier));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Thread_2(data_1, barrier));
```

You then need to put `barrier.await()` calls in each thread. Like so:

```java
   public void run() {
        int rnd_x = 0;
        int rnd_y = 0;

        for (int i = 0 ; i<10; i++)
        {
            rnd_x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            rnd_y = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            data_obj.update(rnd_x,rnd_y);
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Randomized " + rnd_x + " For x and " + rnd_y + " For y, New x: " + data_obj.getX() + ", New y: " + data_obj.getY());


            barrier.await(); //let thread2 know you've produced a number
            barrier.await(); //Wait for thread2 to consume the number
        }
   }
```

```java
   public void run() {

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            //Wait for Thread1 to produce a number
            barrier.await(); 

            System.out.println("Thread 2: Difference number " + i + " Is: " + data_obj.getDiff());

            barrier.await(); //Let thread1 know you've consumed the number

    }
```

---

This should work, and it's neat - but it's a bad idea to do this in actual production code. The main problem is it's complicated to follow - remember that lesson you had where someone explained why `goto` was a bad idea? Well here you have a similar thing where your code is affected by some other code somewhere else. Worse - if one thread throws an exception the other thread will be stuck at the barrier forever.

Unfortunately in order to advise you better on how to avoid synchronization stuff we'd need to know more about what you're trying to do in the first place. However you probably want a `SynchronousQueue`.

More info here:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-cyclic-barrier
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronous-queue

Comment: Very cool solution, But I need to use wait / nofity or locks to solve this problem.

Comment: @DvirPeretz - fine I'm guessing this is some sort of homework question ;).  In that case Thread 1 calls `object.notify();` once it has produced - then it calls `object.wait()` to wait for the consume. Thread 2 calls `object.wait()` to wait for the data then `object.notify()`. You need to be careful on startup too that Thread2 is waiting before thread1 notifies the first time.